# Puppeteer browser.newPage() timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to open multiple browsers and several pages inside each browser. The time interval between openings is specified in `absolutePostingTimestamps`. The problem is in opening a new page instance. I got the following error:

```
/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:61
        _Callback_error.set(this, new Errors_js_1.ProtocolError());
                                  ^

ProtocolError: Target.createTarget timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.
    at new Callback (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:61:35)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:106:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:216:26)
    at Connection.send (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:210:21)
    at CDPBrowser._createPageInContext (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:272:94)
    at CDPBrowserContext.newPage (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:565:78)
    at CDPBrowser.newPage (/home/user/Reddit/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:266:78)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/user/Reddit/test.js:299:48)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Node.js v18.16.0
```

What would you suggest for this issue?
Here is an example of code that I use. I'm not sure that the way I'm executing the procedure is right so I'm putting here a whole function (simplified).

```
var browserOpener = function(browser_name, link, offsets, absolutePostingTimestamps, websites) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(browser_name);
    let resp_port = obj.automation.port;
    let resp_wsEndpoint = obj.automation.wsEndpoint;

    (async () => {
        const port = resp_port; 
        const wsEndpoint = resp_wsEndpoint; 
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
                browserWSEndpoint: `ws://127.0.0.1:${port}${wsEndpoint}`,
                headless: false,
                defaultViewport: null
            });
            for(let i = 0; i < offsets.length; ++i) {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    const page = await browser.newPage();
                    await page.goto(link, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: SELECTOR_SEARCH_TO});                  
                    setTimeout(async () => {
                        console.log('closing page', page.url(), 'for browser', browser_name);
                        if (!page.isClosed()) {
                            await page.close();
                        }
                    }, CLOSING_PAGE_TO);
                    
                    // open a new page

                    if (i < websites.length) {
                        setTimeout(async () => {
                            const newPage = await browser.newPage();

                            const searchQuery = websites[i];
                            if (searchQuery.includes(DATA_SUBSTR)) {
                                await newPage.goto(searchQuery, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: SELECTOR_SEARCH_TO});
                            } 
        
                            setTimeout(async () => {
                                console.log('closing page', newPage.url(), 'for browser', browser_name);
                                if (!newPage.isClosed()) {
                                    await newPage.close();
                                }
                            }, 90000);
                        }, CLOSING_PAGE_TO + 10000);
                    }
                }, offsets[i]);
            }
            
            setTimeout(async () => {
                await browser.close();
            }, offsets[offsets.length - 1] + CLOSING_BROWSER_TO);

        } catch (ex) {
            console.log("Error. Exception caused: " + ex);
            await browser.close();
        }
    })();
};
```